# SQL Difference Between "a%" and "a%_"

Tags: sql, database

I have been searching on good use-cases and differences between the use of LIKE and = where I faced this problem regarding LIKE.

Since LIKE **"_r%"** means **those with 'r' as their second character**, doesn't it hold to assume that **"r%_"** means **those with 'r' as their first character**, essentially making it *functionally same* as "a%".

I am asking this because our lecture slides says the otherwise, and I am not sure whether I am wrong or not. I have also ran this SQL test program (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like_underscore) to see it firsthand and this also proves my point.

Have a good day.

Comment: `%` means zero or more, `_` means exactly one

Comment: Try your query, but filter on `'%deli%n%_'`, or `'%deli%n%'`

Comment: i think this question is ORACLE specific and not common to all DBMS

Answer (score 2):

No, both `r%_` and `r%` don't actually mean the same thing.  The first version `r%_` will match any string starting with `r`, followed by zero or more of any character, followed by any single character.  This pattern will match `ra` and `ran`, but it will *not* match single `r`.  The pattern `r%` on the other hand will match `r`, since `%` allows for zero characters following the leading `r`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `a%` will match anything that starts with `a`, including `a` by itself (`%` matches zero, one, or multiple characters), while `a%_` will match anything that starts with `a`, but *must* be followed by at least one other character (`_` matches exactly one character).